# Loading a JSON into AngularJS Project Globally

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

The  angular project I am working on is adding a configuration file to it. The configuration file is loaded as a JSON, it contains strings that will be replacing the static strings that are currently used in the current version of the project. There is multiple modules where the JSON's data needs to be used, what would be the best way to make the JSON file global throughout the project? I was thinking about loading it separately in each module using a HTTP GET, but I need the JSON to be loaded before everything else.

Thanks.

Comment: depends what `before everything else` means. Is it needed in routing config for example?

Comment: Yes, when the project loads, all of the strings used in the HTML will be from this JSON so I need it to load before everything.

Comment: one way is use javascript variable in a script tag. Otherwise if use ajax will need to manually bootstrap angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can use a service. define a object on the scope and on that define the JSON. create a function which returns the JSON and inject it wherever the need arises. Implementation maybe like:

```
app.service("commonService", ["$log", function($log){
    this.myConfiguration = {
        id:"0",
        name:"abc"
    };
    this.mystatic = function(){
        return myConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Now you can inject it and use in a controller as:

```
app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope, commonService){
    $scope.static = commonService.myStatic();
    //other code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#value):

```
// create the module as usual
angular.module("myapp",[/*...*/]);
// on any other app point, set your json:
angular.module("myapp").value("myjson",{/*...*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need is before you do any routing you could use a service. This is what a config service could look like:

(untested)

```
app.service('ConfigService', function ($q, $http) {

    // loads the config file
    this.loadConfig: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(angular.isDefined(this.config) && this.config.length){
            deferred.resolve(this.config);
        }
        $http.get('config.json')
            .success(function(response) {
                this.config = response;
                deferred.resolve(this.config);
            })
            .error(function(){
                deferred.reject('Could not load "config.json" file');
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // returns a config setting
    this.get: function(key){
        // if the config is not loaded yet, load it and call self
        if(!angular.isDefined(this.config) || !this.config.length){
            this.loadConfig().then(function(){
                return this.get(key);
            })
        }

        // config is loaded. Return requested key
        if(angular.isDefined(config[key])){
            return config[key];
        }else{
            console.error( 'Could not load config value: ' + key );
            return false;
        }
    };

});
```